# ul insertBefore throws Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

First of all, sorry if this is a noob error, I'm new to JS and Stack Overflow and I really can't figure this one out. I'm working on making a todo list app, with multiple todo lists and I have a function that takes the page number and returns the list element (I have all the todo lists on the same html file and I'm using Swipe.js to move between pages). I have an attribute on each `ul` element called list and the function uses JQuery to find the list item that matches the page number. Here is the function:

```
// Return target list based on page number
function returnList(listNumber, completed) {
var list;

if (listNumber == 0 && completed == false) {
    list = $("ul[list='todo1']")
} else if (listNumber == 0 && completed == true) {
    list = $("ul[list='completed1']")
} else if (listNumber == 1 && completed == false) {
    list = $("ul[list='todo2']")
} else if (listNumber == 1 && completed == true) {
    list = $("ul[list='completed2']")
} else if (listNumber == 2 && completed == false) {
    list = $("ul[list='todo3']")
} else if (listNumber == 2 && completed == true) {
    list = $("ul[list='completed3']")
} else if (listNumber == 3 && completed == false) {
    list = $("ul[list='todo4']");
} else if (listNumber == 3 && completed == true) {
    list = $("ul[list='completed4']");
} else {
    console.log("It's broken. Yay!");
}

return list;
}
```

I then have another function that takes the `ul` element and adds a list item with buttons, etc. to it. I'm using insertBefore. Here is that function:

```
//Adds a new item to the todo list
function addItemToDOM(text, completed, listNumber) {
var list = returnList(listNumber, completed);
console.log(list);

var item = document.createElement('li');
item.innerText = text;

var buttons = document.createElement('div');
buttons.classList.add('buttons');

var remove = document.createElement('button');
remove.classList.add('remove');
remove.innerHTML = removeSVG;

// Add click event for removing the item
remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

var complete = document.createElement('button');
complete.classList.add('complete');
complete.innerHTML = completeSVG;

// Add click event for completing the item
complete.addEventListener('click', completeItem);

buttons.appendChild(remove);
buttons.appendChild(complete);
item.appendChild(buttons);

console.log(list.childNodes);
list.insertBefore(item, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

However, when I run `list.insertBefore` it says throws an error on the `list.childNodes[0]` saying there are no child nodes.

Here is the HTML code for the list, if you need it:

```
<div class="container">
            <h3 class="listTitle">Do Now</h3>

            <!-- Uncompleted tasks -->
            <ul class="todo" id="todo" list="todo1"></ul>


            <!-- Completed tasks -->
            <ul class="todo" id="completed" list="completed1"></ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what is op of console.log(list.childNodes);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `returnList` returns a jQuery object, which doesn't have the `childNodes` property. Thus the error is expected.

You can use [`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the reference to DOM element, then `childNodes` property can be used.

```
var elem = returnList(listNumber, completed)
//Also handler if undefined is returned from the function
if(elem == undefined){
   return;
}
var list = elem.get(0);
```

---

You can just use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function with the jQuery object.

```
list.prepend(item);
```